# How do I asynchronously enumerate a collection in an ASP.NET environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, async-await

My environment is ASP.NET Core and EF Core. I need to asynchronously "page" a collection of entities, during a request.

So I created this collection class:

```
public class PagedList<T> : IEnumerable<T> { /* ... */ }
```

And this extension method for async enumeration:

```
public static async Task<PagedList<T>> ToPagedListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, int pageSize, int pageNumber) {
    return await Task.Run(() => new PagedList<T>(items, pageSize, pageNumber));
}
```

And now I can do this:

```
var stuff = await repository.CreateQueryableForLoadingStuff().ToPagedListAsync(10, 1);
```

I looked at the [source for EF's `ToListAsync()`](http://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2130) for guidance - it doesn't just wrap the sync operation as I've done, but rather asynchronously enumerates directly into a new collection. [I also saw this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25723271/7059613) which explains that a `FooAsync()` method isn't "really" async if it starts a new thread using `Task.Run()`, and since I'm operating within an ASP.NET request, that may be the wrong approach.

*Is my way correct for my environment (ASP.NET Core and EF Core), or should use the approach in that link? Also, should I use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`?*

Comment: This is a bad technique for ASP.NET. All you're doing is creating a thread. Every ASP.NET request already occurs on a thread pool thread. Why create an additional thread? Also, it's hard to see from your example, but it almost looks like you plan to do the paging in C#? Why not let the database do it? It will be significantly more efficient. If you only want 10 rows, don't return all 10000 and then select the first 10, simply use `Skip` and `Take` to grab the results you need.

Comment: @dman2306 The `PagedList` class uses EF's `Skip` and `Take` to do paging on the database. It's the async enumeration I'm concerned about.  So, if it is bad for ASP.NET, what should I do instead?

Comment: You'd want to do something like EF does. The goal is the make the I/O async. Meaning, while you're waiting for the socket to read data, you want the ASP.NET request thread to return to the thread pool while it is not in use as the OS waits for IO.

Comment: @dman2306 Please add that 2nd comment as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misplacing your async component.  You want the async on the I/O part (EF/Repository), not the in-memory part (`PagedList`), so how about this instead:

```
public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, int pageSize, int pageNumber) {
    return new PagedList<T>(items, pageSize, pageNumber);
}
```

Then you can do this...

```
var stuff = (await repository.CreateQueryableForLoadingStuffAsync()).ToPagedList(10, 1);
```

...which is just a couple of brackets away from what you first intended.

Edit: as in the comments, this will not let you effectively use the queryable to constrain the SQL query, and you'll be paging in memory.  As an alternative to have the queryable work effectively, look at [PagedList and Async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574315/pagedlist-and-async)

Comment: I think that was just a typo. But it isn't realy the issue - it's not a syntax problem. It's about whether offloading the enumeration onto a new thread, or asynchronously enumerating into a new collection, is better in an ASP.NET environment.

Comment: Also this approach would pull down the entire table, then perform paging in memory. Whereas my PagedList class issues the `Skip` and `Take` as I mentioned above, so it needs to be part of the async operation.

Comment: True, but the PagedList constructors take an IQueryable, not a Task<IQueryable>, so you seem a bit stuck there if you want to use them.  I've added an edit with a link to another option.

Comment: My paging is done on the db. I'm using something similar to the library you linked to. The comment above is correct, which is that what I posted is no good. I ended up doing alsmost exactly what they do in EF's async methods.

Comment: If you now have a good answer (ideally with some code) it's worth posting it as an answer to your own question, so anyone with the same issue in future who finds the question knows to resolve it.